# Microsoft MS SQL System Tables

Tags: sql-server-2008

How I see into `MsSql sys.sysprocesses` 
 can I modify it?

**Example :**

```
select count(spid) from master.dbo.sysprocesses
```

The result will be what I want

Comment: Why would you want to _modify_ that? What problem are you trying to solve by modifying it?

Comment: I have Program in the my Computer and That control users count from SQL connection .And I want Delete That table's row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dan has stated, sys schema objects cannot be modified, you will get an error if you try to do so.

The `sys.sysproccesses` view can be queried using the statement you have posted from a query window and will return results

```
select count(spid) from master.dbo.sysprocesses
```

If you are really wanting to "modify" which I assume means you want to update values, drop rows and such, you can add to a temp table and modify that but the data is a copy so anything you do will not affect the underlying view

```
SELECT *
INTO   #MyTable
FROM   sys.sysprocesses
```

Comment: I have Program in the my Computer and That control users count from SQL connection .And I want Delete That table's row

Comment: you mean you want to kill a connection?

Answer (score 0):

`sysprocesses` is a view and a legacy one at that. One cannot modify system objects.

You can create your own view to encapsulate DMV queries:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.YourView
SELECT COUNT(session_id) AS SessionCount
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions;
GO
```